# jQuery - Using the foreach index in an inside click event

Tags: jquery, ajax, global-variables, local-variables

I am retrieving a collection of 1'108 items with AJAX, and so I need to create an HTML tag with a specific click event for each of them. So now my code inside the ajax success function is:

```
for (var item in itemCollection){
$("#myContainer").append('<a id="item-'+itemCollection[item].index+'" style="..."></a>'); //Works, creates #index-1, #index-2, ... #index-1108

var itemIndex = itemCollection[item].index;
console.log(itemIndex); //Index OK, logs "1", "2", ... "1108"

$("#item-"+itemCollection[item]).click(function(){ //Click Event OK, it is on the correct tag

    //doSomethingWith(itemIndex);
    console.log(itemIndex); //Index not OK, it is always 1108 wherever I click
});
}
```

As you can see the itemIndex used by the click function is always the last one, so I want to "capture" the current itemIndex when I declare the click function, in order to use it inside the function. How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`itemIndex` is being overwritten in the loop.

You can use data attributes if you want to retrieve specific information for each anchor tag.

Try adding `data-index="itemCollection[item].index"`:

```
$("#myContainer").append('<a data-index="itemCollection[item].index" id="item-'+itemCollection[item].index+'" style="..."></a>');
```

In the click event do:

```
$("#item-"+itemCollection[item]).click(function(){ //Click Event OK, it is on the correct tag

    var currIndex = $(this).attr("data-index");
    console.log(currIndex); //Index not OK, it is always 1108 wherever I click
});
```

Comment: Wow a lot of quick answers today! This one solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$("#item-"+itemCollection[item]).click(function(){ 
    console.log(itemCollection[item].index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all about scope. If you enclose your whole click function inside an anonymous function you create what's called a closure.

http://jsfiddle.net/nzs20z8j/10/

```
var itemCollection =  [
        [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "$3,120", "2011/04/25", "Edinburgh", 5421 ],
        [ "Garrett Winters", "Director", "$8,422", "2011/07/25", "Edinburgh", 8422 ],        
    ]

for (index in itemCollection){
    $("#myContainer").append('<a id="item-'+index+'" style="" href="#">link' + index +'</a><br/>');     
    (function(){
        var i = index;
        $("#item-" + index).click(function(event){                              
            alert("you clicked link " + i);
        });
    })();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happend because your itemIndex  changes in every iteration, if you want to call itemIndex you could try this

```
for (var item in itemCollection){
$("#myContainer").append('<a id="item-'+itemCollection[item].index+'" 
itemIndex = "' + itemCollection[item].index + '"style="..."></a>'); //Works, creates #index-1, #index-2, ... #index-1108


$("#item-"+itemCollection[item]).click(function(){ //Click Event OK, it is on the correct tag

//doSomethingWith(itemIndex);
console.log($(this).attr('itemIndex'));
});
```

}